# How do I integrate my Spring project with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have done a small Employee project using Springs. 
This project helps to add,edit,delete the employee in the database.
I had used normal JDBC for the database connection.
Now I want to integrate Hibernate into my project. Please help me. I m learning hibernate and I trying something out of it.

**This is my employee controller.**

```
  package com.employee.controller;

import com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.employee.model.Employee;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired 
    EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView employee() {
        return new ModelAndView("registration", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addemployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee/*, ModelMap model*/) {
        try {
            employeeDao.create(employee.getFirstName(), employee.getEmailId(), employee.getAge());
            return "1";


        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "2";

        }

    }

    @RequestMapping("/ViewEmployeeDetails")
    public String FetchEmployeeDetails(@ModelAttribute Employee employee,ModelMap map,HttpSession session) throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("Inside FetchEmployye details");
        Employee e=new Employee();
        ArrayList<Employee> xx=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        xx=employeeDao.listEmployee();
        System.out.println("Prinitgn List Size..!!! "+xx.size());
        map.addAttribute("EmpDetails", xx);
        session.setAttribute("EmpDetails", xx);
        return "viewnew";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/EditUserDEtails")
    public String EditUserDEtails(@ModelAttribute/*("UserEditDetails")*/  Employee employee,ModelMap map,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside EditUserDEtails");

        String Id=req.getParameter("empId");

        int val=Integer.parseInt(Id);

        System.out.println("Employee ID is..!! "+Id);
        ArrayList<Employee> xx=new ArrayList<Employee>();


        xx=(ArrayList<Employee>) session.getAttribute("EmpDetails");
        ArrayList<Employee> Newxx=new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Employee e1=new Employee();

        for (int i = 0; i < xx.size(); i++) {

            if(val==xx.get(i).getEmpId())
            {
                e1.setAge(xx.get(i).getAge());
                e1.setEmailId(xx.get(i).getEmailId());
                e1.setEmpId(xx.get(i).getEmpId());
                e1.setFirstName(xx.get(i).getFirstName());
                Newxx.add(e1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("hhhh:"+e1.getFirstName());
        map.put("UserEditDetails", e1);
    //  map.put("yyy",Newxx);
        return "edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView view() {
        return new ModelAndView("view", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/viewemployee")
    public String viewEmployee() {
        return "viewnew";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit() {

        return new ModelAndView("edit", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/editemployee" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee/*@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String emailId, @RequestParam int age*/){

        try {

            int id = employee.getEmpId();
            String firstName = employee.getFirstName();
            String emailId = employee.getEmailId();
            int age = employee.getAge();
            /*int id=1;
            String firstName="nitesh";
            String emailId="nitesh";
            int age=25;*/


                String check= employeeDao.update(id, firstName, emailId, age);
                if (check=="1") {
                    return "1";
                }else {
                 return "2";
                }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "2";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete() {
        return new ModelAndView("delete", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/deleteemployee")
    public String deleteEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {
        try {
            int id = employee.getEmpId();

            String check =employeeDao.delete(id);
            if (check=="1") {
            return "1";
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "2";
        }
        return "2";


    }

}
```

**This is my dao impl**

```
package com.employee.dao.impl;


import com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.employee.mapping.EmployeeMapper;
import com.employee.model.Employee;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.Select;

public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDAO{
    private DataSource dateSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dateSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    }

    public void create(String firstName, String emailId, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "insert into Employee (firstName, emailId, age) values (?, ?, ?)";

          jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL,firstName,emailId,age);
          System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + firstName + " Age = " + age);
          return;       
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployee(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        Connection con = dateSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection done");

        String SQL = "select * from Employee where empId= "+id;
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name

              emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empId"));

              emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
             emp.setEmailId(rs.getString("emailId")); 
              emp.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));

          return emp;
    }
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Employee> listEmployee() throws SQLException {

        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 =null;
        Connection con = dateSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection done");

        String SQL = "select * from Employee";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(SQL);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
//      ResultSet rs=stmt.getResultSet();

        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXX :"+rs.toString());

        while(rs.next()){
             //Retrieve by column name
                emp1=new Employee();
                System.out.println("Getting values in result Set..!!!");
              emp1.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empId"));
              emp1.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
              emp1.setEmailId(rs.getString("emailId")); 
              emp1.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
              emp.add(emp1);


    }
        rs.close();
        con.close();
         return (ArrayList<Employee>) emp;


    }

    @Override
    public String delete(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        /*String SQL = "delete from Employee where id = ?";
          jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
          System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
          return;*/
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        System.out.println("deleting the connetion ");
        Connection con = dateSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection establised");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String sql1 = "select * from Employee where empId="+id;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
        while(rs.next()) {
            emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empId"));
        }
        if(emp.getEmpId() == 0) {
            return "2"; 
        }else {
        String SQL = "delete from Employee where empId="+id;
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
        System.out.println("deleted");
        return "1";
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String update(Integer id, String firstName, String emailId, Integer age) throws SQLException {
    /*  String SQL = "update employee set age = ? set firstName= ? setemailId=? where id = ?";
          jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, firstName,emailId,age, id);
          System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
          return;*/
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        System.out.println("editing the connection ");
        Connection con = dateSource.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection establised");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql1 = "select * from Employee where empId="+id;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
        while(rs.next()) {
            emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empId"));
        }
        if(emp.getEmpId()==0) {
        return "2";
        }else {

        String SQL = "update Employee set firstName='"+firstName+"',  emailId =  '"+emailId +"', age ='"+age+"' where empId="+id;
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
        System.out.println("updated");
        return "1";
        }
    }
    /*public Employee check(Integer id) throws SQLException {



    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    Connection con = dateSource.getConnection();
    System.out.println("connection done");

    String SQL = "select empId from Employee where empId= "+id;
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

    while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name

          emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empId"));
          return emp;

    }
    return emp;
    }
    */

    @Override
    public Employee check(Integer id) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee fetchEmployeeDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is my employee mapper**

```
package com.employee.mapping;

import com.employee.model.Employee;
public class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee> {


       public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
          Employee emp = new Employee();
          emp.setEmpId( rs.getInt("id"));
          emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("name"));
          emp.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
/*        emp.setEmailId(rs.getString("emailId"));*/
          return emp;

    }
}


**This is my Spring-servlet.xml**

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.employee.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databasename=Employee"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value="r@1234"/>

    </bean>


   <bean id="employeedaoimpl" 
      class="com.employee.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>

<!--    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:/Employee" id="employee"></jee:jndi-lookup> -->


</beans>
```

**This is my Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Employee</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password">r@1234</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.employee.model.Employee"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

***please help me to integrate this project with hibernate***

Comment: You don' need to post all the code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You already post all views but we need to see your applicationContext.xml? You need to define SessionFactory as a bean inside the spring context.

Comment: You can remove all your JSPs. You need to add your spring context.xml where you define `LocalSessionFactoryBean` or `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: SO is not really meant for tutorials :) A quick google search will give lot of tutorial links like [this](http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/) and [this](http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4).

Comment: While its ok to being new to something, some basic research is required prior to post a question - google knows everything, just give a sincere try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define DataSource & Hibernate SessionFactory in the spring
   application context file.
2. To integrate the Hibernate with your application DAO class - you
   can either use 'HibernateTemplate' OR directly inject the Hibernate
   sesisonFactory in your DAO class.

refer - http://www.javabench.in/2012/04/spring-hibernate-integration.html